# Networkx graph_from_place: no path between pair of point, how to solve?

Tags: python, graph, networkx, shortest-path

When I create a networkx graph from OSM (of Turin, Italy), and I try to run the shortest path between different pairs of nodes. It said that there is no path. I have checked and among most pairs of points, there are no paths. How is it possible since I have downloaded the graph from OSM and a node is a junction between two edges?

```
G = ox.graph_from_place('Torino, Italy')
nodi=[]
for i in G.nodes():
   nodi.append(i)

print(len(nodi))
print(len(G.edges()))

false=0
true=0
for i in nodi:
  for j in nodi:
    if i!=j:
      a=G.has_edge(i, j)
      if a==False:
        false+=1
      if a==True:
        true+=1

print(false)
print(true)


24976
62072

623714119
61481
```

When I run the shortest path, this is the error. In the example below I selected some origin and destination from an excel.

```
df=pd.read_excel('Ori_Ex.xlsx')
origin=[]

for index, row in df.iterrows():

   lat=row['lat']
   lon=row['lon']
   origin_point=(lat,lon)
   origin_node = ox.get_nearest_node(G, origin_point) 
   origin.append(origin_node)

done=[]

for i in origin: 
    orig=i
    for j in origin:
        if orig!=j:
            check = j+orig
            if check not in done:
               done.append(check)
               dest=j
               path=nx.shortest_path(G, source = orig, target=dest, weight = 'length')

               print('ok')

ok
ok
ok
ok
ok
ok
ok
ok
ok
ok
ok
ok
ok
ok
ok
ok
ok
ok
ok
ok
ok
ok
ok
ok
ok
ok
ok
ok
ok
ok
ok
ok
ok
ok
ok
ok
ok
ok
ok
ok
ok
ok
ok
ok
ok
ok
ok
ok
ok
ok
ok
ok
ok
ok
ok
ok
ok
ok
ok
ok
ok
ok
ok
ok
ok
ok
ok

---------------------------------------------------------------------------

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/networkx/algorithms/shortest_paths/weighted.py in multi_source_dijkstra(G, sources, target, cutoff, weight)
    743     try:
--> 744         return (dist[target], paths[target])
    745     except KeyError:

KeyError: 262294804


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

NetworkXNoPath                            Traceback (most recent call last)

4 frames

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/networkx/algorithms/shortest_paths/weighted.py in multi_source_dijkstra(G, sources, target, cutoff, weight)
    744         return (dist[target], paths[target])
    745     except KeyError:
--> 746         raise nx.NetworkXNoPath("No path to {}.".format(target))
    747 
    748 

NetworkXNoPath: No path to 262294804.
```

Comment: It will help to answer the question if you can share a [mcve]

Comment: I added an example

Comment: That would suggest to me that within the graph there is no path from the source node to the target node.  You should look at those nodes to see what is happening.  Perhaps there are one-way streets or some other peculiarity.

Answer (score -1):

Your code shows that most places are not directly connected to one another.  `has_edge` checks whether the graph has them directly connected, rather than having a path.

Try `G.has_path(i,j)`

---

As a note, in your code:

```
a=G.has_edge(i, j)
      if a==False:
        false+=1
      if a==True:
        true+=1
```

can be rewritten more clearly as:

```
if G.has_edge(i,j):
    true += 1
else:
    false += 1
```

Comment: I post an extra example of the problem